# How to count the elements preceding and succeeding an element in an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have an arraylist and I want to know how many elements exist before a specific element and how many elements succeed it. How can I do this?

```
 ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
 aList.add(-0.15);
 aList.add(-0.10);
 aList.add(-0.05);
 aList.add(0.00);
 aList.add(0.05);
 aList.add(0.10);
 aList.add(0.15);

double itemToBeFound = -0.05;
for(int n=0; n<aList.size(); n++){

    //How many element before

    double tmpEl = Double.parseDouble(aList.get(n).toString());
    if(itemToBeFound==tmpEl){                
         System.out.println("find it!");
    }
    //How many element after    
}
```

Comment: Math? If you have the index of the item the rest is math. Are you asking how to find an item in a list?

Comment: You can count how many elements in the found element is, and you know the size of the whole list; those two are enough to determine the number of successors.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to convert your `double` to a `String` and back again.

Comment: When your if statement is true, `n` will have a particular value. Can you see how that value relates to the number of elements before `itemToBeFound`?

Comment: Sorry your question was closed; I thought it was fine and was writing an answer when it was closed. The short answer is to use [`ArrayList.indexOf`][https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)] and [`ArrayList.size`][https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()].

Comment: Additionally when making an `ArrayList` or other `Collection` you should specify what it contains, for example `ArrayList<Double> aList = new ArrayList<>()`. Doing so will protect you from adding the wrong type to your list, for example your code won't compile if you try to add a `String` to a `List` of `Double`s. As noted in another comment there's no need to convert `double` to `String`. If you still need to loop over your `List` then it may be better to declare `List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>()` and convert to `String` when adding to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: **Voting to re-open.** This may not be the most useful or insightful of questions, but it is a valid question with sufficient detail.

Comment: `int atIndex = aList.indexOf(itemToBeFound); int itemsBefore = atIndex; int itemsAfter = (aList.size() - 1) - atIndex;`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `indexOf(Object o):`
"Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element" - Javadoc

```
int index = indexOf(itemToBeFound);
int elementsBefore = index;
int elementsAfter = aList.size()-1;
```

Note that the the line:

```
double tmpEl = Double.parseDouble(aList.get(n).toString());
```

Does not seems to be useful here.

Comment: conversion to double, is useful, because through just indexOf() you get -1.